# How to detect that finish an animation Lottie and show a Toast

Tags: android, android-studio

I have this code that shows an animation, I want to know how to show a Toast when the animation is over

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    lottieAnimationLogo = findViewById(R.id.lottieAnimationLogo);

    startCheckAnimationLogo();

}

private void startCheckAnimationLogo(){
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f).setDuration(3000);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation){
            lottieAnimationLogo.setProgress((Float)animation.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
    if(lottieAnimationLogo.getProgress() == 0f){
        animator.start();
    }else{
        lottieAnimationLogo.setProgress(0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try set AnimatorListener:

```
animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            // show Toast
        }
    });
```

Or add listener for all lifecycle events:

```
animator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
```

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    lottieAnimationLogo = findViewById(R.id.lottieAnimationLogo);

    startCheckAnimationLogo();

}

private void startCheckAnimationLogo(){
    ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 1f).setDuration(3000);
    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation){
 lottieAnimationLogo.setProgress((Float)animation.getAnimatedValue());
        }
    });
    animator.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    if(lottieAnimationLogo.getProgress() == 0f){
        animator.start();
    }else{
        lottieAnimationLogo.setProgress(0f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am very new with this, in the code that I put as I would have to adapt that to make it work?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You can do `Toast.makeText(this, "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` in `onAnimationEnd` method for showing toast after animation.

Comment: I need that when the animation ends show a message, with that I can continue because in reality what I do next is validate connection to the internet and if you have to send an activity and if not show another animation that there is no internet, but to be able to advance I need that, detect when I finish the animation to do something else

Comment: I do not know how to adapt that code that you pass to me so that it works, goes inside startCheckAnimationLogo?

Comment: Oh man you are the master, I do not know where you are from but here in Argentina it is 2 AM and I am from 23 PM trying to do that #TrueStory